# How do i get sIFR 3 to align right and use the full width

Tags: sifr, text-alignment

Well like i stated in the title, i cant get sifr to align right and use the full width of the containing h3 tag. Aligning text to the right works well, but i want the text to be on 1 or 2 lines instead of 3 and how it looks the text should perectly fit on 1 or 2 lines :/.

Link: http://hendriks.adena.nl/preview/html/?p=kerst

Anyone got any thoughts on this problem?

Niels

Comment: Thank you Simon, i tried 100% before, but it diddnt work. But when i set the width too 210px it worked, never thought about that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the width of the sifr elements is determined based on the width of the original text content that is in the a tags within the h3 tags (check your page with javascript off to see the difference in width).

So one simple solution should be to give these a and/or h3 an explicit width - my guess is that sifr will use that with. (Maybe you can also use 100%, I'm not sure about that)

Comment: Thank you Simon, i tried 100% before, but it diddnt work. But when i set the width too 210px it worked, never thought about that. Thanks again!